# Can't catch range out of bounds exception in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, exception, substring, nsrange

I'm getting this error message in xCode:

```
-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {18446744073709551615, 1} out of bounds; string length 71. This will become an exception for apps linked after 10.10 and iOS 8. Warning shown once per app execution.
```

I'm trying to find where in my code this is happening.

I have about a dozen substringWithRange methods in my project. I put try catch blocks around all of them:

```
 @try {
        substring = [s substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, j - i)];
    }
    @catch (NSException* e) {
        NSLog(@"Except: %@", e);
    }
```

None of the catch blocks are being executed.

I tried setting my deployment target to 8.4.

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: You don't need try/catch. Use the debugger to see where the app crashes.

Comment: It doesn't crash it stalls...

Comment: What do you mean "it stalls"? Do you mean the debugger stops on the line causing the problem?

Comment: The debugger doesn't stop anywhere, although I have breakpoints set to stop on exceptions. Its almost as if it gets caught in an infinite loop. I get the error then nothing happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The large value 18446744073709551615 is the value of `NSNotFound` (2^64-1, the largest integer that can be represented in 64 bits).

You are probably first looking for a (sub)string in another string or so, but that substring is not found. Rather than a valid index you get back `NSNotFound`. Presumably you didn't expect or test for this special case and passed that `NSNotFound` value into an `NSMakeRange()`, triggering the error there.

If there are only a handful of places where you call `NSMakeRange`, as you indicated, then you should be able to (1) verify this hypothesis and (2) fix the bug purely by inspection of the code.